# How do I change values in a existing database when input matches a row in Django

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I searched a lot on this site and find parts of my questions, but this one I cannot find. Maybe I didn't use the right keywords and is this a commonly asked question? If so apologies.

I'm trying to match a input value named barcode_input from a form with a model field named barcode. 
If there is a match, print("There is a match!") will show in the Terminal.

The next step will be, that when there is a match, the amount_input value has to be added to the specific model sold field (with which there is a match) and subtracted from the specific model amount_sold field (with which there is a match).

This is my code so far.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class AddProduct(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    barcode = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    stock_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import AddProduct

class ScanProductForm(forms.Form):
    barcode_input = forms.IntegerField(label='scan barcode')
    amount_input = forms.IntegerField(label='amount')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ScanProductForm, self).clean()
        barcode_input = cleaned_data.get("barcode_input")
        amount_input = cleaned_data.get("amount_input")

        try:
            p = AddProduct.objects.get(pk=barcode_input)
            p.sold += amount_input
        except AddProduct.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Does not exist")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ScanProductForm

from .models import AddProduct

def scan_product_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ScanProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
                print("There is a match!")
        else:
            form = ScanProductForm()

        return render(request, 'scanapp/barscan.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Django's F expression for this kind of work.
**forms.py**

```
from django.db.models import F
from django import forms
from .models import AddProduct

class ScanProductForm(forms.Form):
    barcode_input = forms.IntegerField(label='scan barcode')
    amount_input = forms.IntegerField(label='amount')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ScanProductForm, self).clean()
        barcode_input = cleaned_data.get("barcode_input")
        amount_input = cleaned_data.get("amount_input")

        try:
            p = AddProduct.objects.get(pk=barcode_input)

            p.sold = F('sold') +  amount_input
            p.save()
        except AddProduct.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Does not exist")
```

> A better approach is to validate only barcode input field in forms.py
>   and move the logic of updating object into views.py.

**forms.py**

```
class ScanProductForm(forms.Form):
    barcode_input = forms.IntegerField(label='scan barcode')
    amount_input = forms.IntegerField(label='amount')
    def clean_barcode_input(self):
        barcode_input = self.cleaned_data['barcode_input']
        qs = AddProduct.objects.filter(pk=barcode_input)
        if qs.exists():
            return barcode_input
        raise forms.ValidationError("Barcode does not exist")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import F
from .forms import ScanProductForm
from .models import AddProduct

def scan_product_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScanProductForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("There is a match!")
            barcode_input = form.cleaned_data.get("barcode_input")
            amount_input = form.cleaned_data.get("amount_input")
            p = AddProduct.objects.get(pk=barcode_input)
            p.sold = F("sold") + amount_input
            p.save()
        else:
            form = ScanProductForm()
        return render(request, 'scanapp/barscan.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. This broadens my django/python vocabulary :-) Also thanks for the suggestion to do the logic in views.py!

Comment: Glad to help you.